# OpenBSD pkg_info not finding package?

Tags: openbsd

I can see that the [UniFi port is present this ports list](https://openports.se/net/unifi/6.0). However, running `pkg_info -Q unifi` yields no results.

**How do I determine why this is occurring?**

I tested with `pkg_info -Q unzip` and it responds fine:

```
system# whoami
root
system# pkg_info -Q unifi
system# pkg_info -Q unzip
unzip-6.0p14
unzip-6.0p14-iconv
system#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learned that some ports (like `UniFi`) are not distributed with the base system. In order to add these types of packages, the [ports tree needs to be configured](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/ports.html).